# Optimize animation with javascript assigning value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am building an animation with lots of effects and animation in a website. I am trying to optimize the efficiency of those animations since some of them are a little complex to low CPU/RAM devices. The animations are not smooth as I want as you can see here https://www.empresasite.com.br

So I realize in many parts of my code I do this:

```
var x = 38; //this value changes every 50ms
document.getElementById("a").style.left = document.getElementById("b").style.left = document.getElementById("c").style.left = document.getElementById("d").style.left = document.getElementById("e").style.left = x + "px";
```

Actually it's a simplification above, I run the code above with at least 13 elements `a = b = c = d .... m = x;` and at least with 4 properties (left, height, box-shadow and background-color).

So I was wondering if there is any better alternative to assign the same value to multiple elements/objects at once?

Maybe the code below would be faster? I used it but I didnt see a significant improvement in animation, maybe I should have seen it?

```
var x = 38;
x = x + "px";
document.getElementById("a").style.left = x;
document.getElementById("b").style.left = x;
document.getElementById("c").style.left = x;
document.getElementById("d").style.left = x;
document.getElementById("e").style.left = x;
```

I think the code above should be faster right? I say this cause every element updates its own property (`left`) retrieving the value from "x". In the first example I gave MAYBE javascript is assigning the value of the previous element in the chain of "=" sign so it has to assign "x" to the first element then assign the value of the first element to the second... go on.

Do you know exactly what jquery does when I use this:

```
$(".elements").css({left:x});
```

Does it use some optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with most of the javascript benchmarking tools online I came up to this conclusion:

1) Jquery is the faster method of all native js solutions I used. Maybe Jquery uses some sort of optimization when you apply the same property to lots of elements at once! So you should rely on `$(".class").css("left",x)` to apply the x value to left property for hundreds of elements and it will be the faster solution;

2) The second solution is apply x individually TO EACH element. Example:

```
var x = 38;
document.getElementById("a").style.left = x;
document.getElementById("b").style.left = x;
```

3) The worst solution was actually the one I was using in the website that I was facing not smooth animations. So avoid this:

```
document.getElementById("a").style.left = document.getElementById("b").style.left = ... = ... = x;
```

The difference from the 1st solution to the 3rd is really noticeable. You can check it in the links below (pay special attention to the animation at the top):

1) https://www.empresasite.com.br/?q=principal&before -> this is using the 3rd solution

2) https://www.empresasite.com.br/?q=principal -> this is using the 1st solution

In a computer with lots of resources you may not see a difference but if you run this in a computer with 4GB of RAM or less you will see a big impact!

Hope this helps anyone that does not have smooth animations!

Answer (score 0):

You could increase performance no-end by using `translate` instead of modifying `position`.

Using the jQuery variation you asked will not make any difference, as you are still modifying position `left`.

Comment: For some reason using translate the operation is moved to GPU and for some reason it looks like I can reach a limit much sooner using GPU than using CPU regardig animation. FOR EXAMPLE: animating hundreds of elements using jquery works (not smooth but it works), however animating those same hunderds of elements using GPU it breaks everything, some animations start, other lose sync...

Comment: You're likely causing lots of repainting, can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: The code is a big mess for now, I am running it in https://www.empresasite.com.br inside the huge animation at the top.